# If limit of $f(x)$ exists and the limit of $g(x)$ dne as $x$ approaches $a$, does limit of $[f(x)+g(x)]$ dne as $x$ approaches $a$.

Tags: limits

If limit of $f(x)$ exists and the limit of $g(x)$ does not exists as $x$ approaches $a$, does limit of $[f(x)+g(x)]$ not exist as $x$ approaches $a$.

I believe that the limit does not exist.  In order for the limit to exist, then limit of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must exist, but I can't seem to find an example where $a is not infinity.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ both exist then the limit of $f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ exists.  Apply this to $f(x) + g(x)$ and $-f(x)$ to get that if those limits exist then the limit of $g(x)$ exists.

Thus if the limit of $f(x)$ exists but the limit of $g(x)$ does *not* exist then the limit of $f(x) + g(x)$ also does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'll clear this up with an example, one that the posted answer probably misses (and the question is not very clear, it does not tell if **a** is finite or not)

Consider,

$\lim_{x \to \infty} ({x+ \sin x}) $ = $+\infty$

Now, consider 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x $
and $\lim_{x \to \infty} x $ - the former doesn't exist, while the latter still approaches $+\infty$

P.S. 
Now, it depends on one's definition of what *limit does not exist* means - several texts say that limits approaching + or - $\infty$, exist (for we can definitively say that as x approaches a certain value, finite or infinite - f(x) definitely approaches some very huge value - tending to infinity) , while others, due to the complex and incomprehensible nature of infinity deem the limit has non-existent.

For finite limits, there's no confusion, and @Jim's answer perfectly describes the situation.